# How Do I Install Outguess Steganography Command on OS X?

Tags: macos, encryption, decryption, steganography

My daughter is leaving for a risky foreign country next week, and the country has some limited Internet censors there. I want to provide a way for her to send me secret steganography messages in any time of danger or potential danger, if this is possible.

I have Ubuntu Linux, so I have learned of the outguess command for it. On OS X, I wanted to know if there's a command line command for this. In other words, how to compile Outguess on OS X.

P.S. Perhaps I am an overly protective father for her, but it's better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: A father concerned about the welfare of his daughter, even a half a world away?  There are fathers who don't even care about their daughters in the same country.  I salute your attitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to compile it from source. You should download the source archives provided, install the OS X Dev Tools provided by Apple, and then build it as you would a standard linux application (typically, run a `configure` script if present, then `make`, then `make install` if such an option is provided). A quick googling does not reveal any prebuilt OS X binaries or packages for this program, but it shouldn't be too hard to get it compiled up yourself.